# I get millions of 'this class is not key-value coding-compliant' errors after upgrading to xCode 4

Tags: xcode4

I upgraded to XCode 4 but seem to be stuck.

After upgrading to XCode 4, every object in ANY of my two nib's (labels, sliders, views, etc) all appear to be 'not key-value coding-compliant'. If I un-wire (delete the connection) an IBOutlet and then re-wire it, the unarchiving process simply creates an error for the next item in the nib during the unarchiving process. HOWEVER:

I realize this example comes with no code. However, I don't think it's the 'code' per se that's causing the problem. When I got the same error in XCode 3.XX, I simply went to the connections inspector for IB and clearly saw a faulty connection. In this instance, I see no faulty connections, but I seem to get an error for EVERY IB object.

Could I have inadvertently sabotaged myself while exploring XCode 4?

Could anyone shed any light on this?

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: I'm having some trouble with Xcode4 too. Wish it didn't overrite my old one, fortunately I still have the .dmg. One of my issues: issue:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326757/xcode-4-waiting-for-process-appname-to-launch

Comment: Exactly the same problem here, did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Related? From [Exception on outlet connections in Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594200/exception-on-outlet-connections-in-xcode-4) :

> I found out the source of the problem. It seems that in the Target for the app the “Main Interface” was set to my MainView which is an instance of UIView. I changed it to MainWindow (generated by Xcode) and all worked fine.