# Xcode 4 "waiting for process 'Appname' to launch

Tags: objective-c, debugging, ios4, xcode4

I installed Xcode 4 and now cannot run one of my iPhone projects.

```
 Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Waiting for process 'AppName' to launch.
```

On the top status bar I see 'Attaching to AppName'.
The only weird thing about the project is it has a dependency on ZXingWidget for QR code scans.

Weirder that it works on a co-workers computer, but not mine.

Tried removing my build directory, no dice.

I can run other iPhone projects from source in Xcode 4 with no problem.

Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: Yeah I've also come across this a few times. For me it's random and I just start the app manually when it happens and the debugger gets attached.

Comment: It's not consistently happening for you? I don't have the app in my current simulator, so I can't run it.

Comment: Random for me too. I usually do a clean/rebuild if it happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A tip I found at the [Apple Developer Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/396965#396965):

> Go into your ProjectName.xcodeproj/
>   directory and delete anything named
>   with your userid.   Re-open the
>   project in xcode and all that will get
>   recreated and it should work. At least
>   it did for me.

Another tip is to manually delete the `build` directory.

Yet another tip is to navigate to the Organizer (<kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd> <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> in xcode 4), select *Projects*, select you application in the left hand side and then the *Delete...*-button to the right of *Derived Data*.

And never forget the universally useful tip: restart your computer and try again.

Good luck!

Answer (score 23):

I ran into the same issue.  Go to Product -> Edit Scheme and select the Run scheme on the lefthand side.  Go to the info tab, and next to launch there will be two options (neither of them selected): 'Automatically' and 'Wait for XXXX.app to Launch'.  Select the Automatically one and it should clear up your issue.

I had actually built and used my projects using xcode 4 for a few days with no issues, and then this popped up randomly. Hope the this helps.

Comment: thanks this saved me a few bangs of the head on the keyboard!

Comment: Thanks, I've got the Run scheme set to Debug, XXXX.app, GDB, Wait for XXXX.app to launch, but still seeing the same thing, the eternal "attaching" message.

Comment: Have you tried using the 'Automatic' option rather than the 'Wait for XXXX.app to launch'? Also make sure you completely quit the Simulator so that it wont be locked up from your earlier incorrect config.

Comment: Tried setting to Automatic, quitting Simulator, stopping process, then started again. Still nothing..

Any idea why this happens? It's only this one app.

Comment: That is frustrating... I am not quite sure to be honest.  If I were you I would grab the latest Xcode version (They released 4.01 recently) or the developer preview of 4.1 and see if that helps.

Comment: In my case, after manually removing the app from simulator, the launch option must be set to 'Automatically', otherwise, the app won't be installed to the simulator. That's why it hangs at waiting for process 'AppName' to launch. Hope this explain part of the weirdness of this problem.

Comment: In my case, I started by deleting derived data (as suggested by Brattberg in another answer), then did a hard data reset in the simulator and a clean, then launched on retina, then restarted the computer. Then, switched to 'automatically' and this worked. It might be that you'll need to do all or several of those things.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to set it to automatic but doing that alone won't be enough. Like Chris says, you will need to exit your simulator manually and then run.

Answer (score 0):

for me it was already set on automatic and still had this problem.
The problem solved after I changed the build configuration to Distribution in the product -> scheme

Answer (score 0):

Quit Xcode. Find the App_Name.xcodeproj, "Show Package Contents" and remove the folder "xcuserdata".

This will clean the "cache" of breakpoints. Start Xcode, compile and done :)

Answer (score 0):

You may be click the bottom of Product>scheme>edit scheme >Waitting for executable to be launched.And you should click the Automatically choose.